# How convert data table?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an Input table (it is a subset) which I would like to convert into proper output as below, but I cannot do it properly.

Input:

```
V1                        V2    V3      V4   
name                     Arch  <NA>     NA     
Concentration   Concentration  1000    500    
Plate 1               WT       70960  48340 
Plate 1               WT       68670 145300 
Plate 1               KNO      49270  19530


df <- data.frame(
V1 = c("name", "Concentration", "Plate 1", "Plate 1", "Plate 1"),
V2 = c("Arch", "Concentration", "WT", "WT", "KNO"),
V3 = c(NA, 1000, 70960, 68670, 49270),
V4 = c(NA, 500, 48340, 145300, 19530),
stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Desire output table:

```
Name  Concentration   Treat     Rep1    Rep2
Arch  1000              WT      70960   68670
Arch  500               WT      48340   145300
Arch  1000              KNO     49270   -
Arch  500               KNO     19530   -
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df[-c(1,2),-1] 
colnames(df2) <- c("Treat",df[2,-c(1,2)])
df2 |> 
  mutate(Name = df$V2[[1]],
         Rep = row_number(),
         .by = Treat) |>
  pivot_longer(c(2,3), 
               names_to = "Concentration") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = Rep,
              names_prefix = "Rep") |>
  select(c(2,3,1,4,5))
```

Gives:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Name  Concentration Treat  Rep1   Rep2
  <chr> <chr>         <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Arch  1000          WT    70960  68670
2 Arch  500           WT    48340 145300
3 Arch  1000          KNO   49270     NA
4 Arch  500           KNO   19530     NA
```

Explanation:

Drop the top two rows (labels not data) and the first column (not needed?)
Then relabel using data from the subset where required:

```
df2 <- df[-c(1,2),-1] 
colnames(df2) <- c("Treat",df[2,-c(1,2)])

> df2
  Treat  1000    500
3    WT 70960  48340
4    WT 68670 145300
5   KNO 49270  19530
```

Next, add the "name" column and number each replicate based on Treat:

```
df2 |> 
  mutate(Name = df$V2[[1]],
         Rep = row_number(),
         .by = Treat) |>

  Treat  1000    500 Name Rep
3    WT 70960  48340 Arch   1
4    WT 68670 145300 Arch   2
5   KNO 49270  19530 Arch   1
```

Now use `pivot_longer()` to combined the 1000 and 500 columns into a new "Concentration" one:

```
  pivot_longer(c(2,3), 
               names_to = "Concentration") |>
# A tibble: 6 × 5
  Treat Name    Rep Concentration  value
  <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>          <dbl>
1 WT    Arch      1 1000           70960
2 WT    Arch      1 500            48340
3 WT    Arch      2 1000           68670
4 WT    Arch      2 500           145300
5 KNO   Arch      1 1000           49270
6 KNO   Arch      1 500            19530
```

Then `pivot_wider()` to spread the replicates from rows into their own columns:

```
  pivot_wider(names_from = Rep,
              names_prefix = "Rep") |>

# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Treat Name  Concentration  Rep1   Rep2
  <chr> <chr> <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl>
1 WT    Arch  1000          70960  68670
2 WT    Arch  500           48340 145300
3 KNO   Arch  1000          49270     NA
4 KNO   Arch  500           19530     NA
```

Finally arrange the columns:

```
  select(c(2,3,1,4,5))
```